# Nginx Subdomains and Rewrite Rules

Tags: nginx, rewrite, wildcard-subdomain

I've been trying to configure Nginx to do what I currently have set up in Apache, but no luck so far.

I would like http://$1.$2.mas.example.com (where $1 and $2 is any subdomain) to point to root with a value of /home/webcontent/$1/mas/$2/html

Any suggestions how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way to do it.. not how you have it laid out but its using the whole hostname as a directory.. I will look deeper into if nginx can do what you want. I know it can do this

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  _;

    location / {
        root   /tmp/$host;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

That will serve up content if you hit http://host1.domain.com in /tmp/host1.domain.com/index.html

**EDIT**

Here is what you want to do

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  _;

    if ($host ~ (.*)\.(.*)\.domain.com) {
            set $myroot /tmp/$1/mas/$2;
    }

    location / {
        root $myroot;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

Comment: This server block won't ever be used unless it's the first one specified. server_name _; is not magical. The listen directive needs to use the [default|default_server] flag for it to get requests. Alternatively if one uses > 0.8.25 you can use named captures in the server_name directive.

Answer (score 0):

Since nginx 0.7.40 you can use regular expression server names.

So the following might work (untested):

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name ~^(\w+)\.(\w+)\.mas\.example\.com$
  root /home/webcontent/$1/mas/$2/html
}
```

See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names